# Elastic search - how to get aggregate nested _source value

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using elastic search to get some data.

please tell me how to get aggregate _source.eventName group data.
like this sql

```
seletc eventName, count(eventName) from events group by eventName;
```

Here is my aggs query and current response data structure.

```
{
    type: 'event',
    size: 3,
    aggs: {
      event_group: {
        terms: {
          field: 'eventName'
        }
      }
    }
}
```

```
"hits": {
  "hits": [
    {
      "_type": "event",
      "_source": {
        "eventName": "event1",
      }
    },
    {
      "_type": "event",
      "_source": {
        "eventName": "event1",
      }
    },
    {
      "_type": "event",
      "_source": {
        "eventName": "event2",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

※ideal case(I wanna get like this result.)

```
{
  "eventName": "event1",
  "count": 2
},
{
  "eventName": "event2",
  "count": 1
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What is your question actually?

Comment: @Val sorry, I updated question

Comment: Your aggregation seems fine, have you run it? What do you get?

Comment: @Val
I wanna get like this result
{
  "eventName": "event1",
  "count": 2
},
{
  "eventName": "event2",
  "count": 1
}

Comment: And what do you get instead with your aggregation?

Comment: @Val I wanna get ※ideal case result. but I don't know how to create parameters.

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch doesn't support this filtering, but you can use the REST API filter parameter which will return you sth like

**GET** .../_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source.*

```
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {...},
        "_source": {...},
        "_source": {...},
       }]
    }
```

Elastic search [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/common-options.html) on common options

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct. If you only want the count of `eventName`s, use `size: 0` there instead of `3`. It will tell ES to not return `hits`.

The response should have an `aggregations` property like so:

```
{
    "aggregations":
        {
            "event_group": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
                "buckets" : [ 
                    {
                        "key" : "event1",
                        "doc_count" : 10
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "event2",
                        "doc_count" : 10
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "event3",
                        "doc_count" : 10
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
}
```

The `doc_count` property there is the count you're looking for.

**Note:** ES will only return the top 10 `eventName` in the bucket. Depending on the ES version you're using, if you want to get all unique `eventName`s, you need to specify a `size` in your `terms` aggregation. Read ES docs for more info.